# Instead of be or instead of being?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, gerunds, ambiguity, bare-infinitives

I know after 'instead of' verb-ing is used.
But I have found a sentence :

> "My father wants me to be bold instead of be cautious".

Is it correct?

Can we use **'instead of being cautious'** in the above sentence?
Please clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is wrong, although not because of the word "be". Ideally, the sentence should use "rather than" and not "instead of". "Rather than" is coordinating; "instead of" is subordinating.

> My father wants me to be bold *rather than be* cautious.

You could also drop the repetition of the verb and just say:

> My father wants me to be bold *rather than* cautious.

Comment: Could you please let me know whether "instead of", as a preposition, is followed by the bare infinitival ?